# How do I programmatically disable the update checks for an Ehcache?

Tags: ehcache

I know that the attribute "updateCheck" can be set in "false" in the XMLlike this:

> xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>   xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../config/ehcache.xsd"
>   updateCheck="false"
>   monitoring="autodetect">

But I need to do this programmatically. How should I do it?

Answer (score 4):

Call this before you use any ehcache functions:

```
System.setProperty("net.sf.ehcache.skipUpdateCheck", "true");
```

Comment: How does one do it in Ehcache 3.7?